# Laravel routing - shorten the urls upto only one URI segment.

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, url-routing

It is said that shorter the URL, better the seo (atleast my client believes on it).

Now am creating website similar to `watchtown.co.uk` in laravel. I need to generate in such a way that the uri should not be more than one segment.

Requirement

I have following urls:

1.Need to change From:

```
localhost/laravelproj/public/brands/brandname/watches
```

to

```
localhost/laravelproj/public/brandname-watches.html
```

---

2.Need to change From:

```
localhost/laravelproj/public/brands/brandname/jewellery
```

to

```
localhost/laravelproj/public/brandname-jewellery.html
```

---

3.Need to change From:

```
localhost/laravelproj/public/categories/categoryname/watches
```

to

```
localhost/laravelproj/public/categoryname-watches.html
```

---

4.Need to change From:

```
localhost/laravelproj/public/categories/categoryname/jewellery
```

to

```
localhost/laravelproj/public/categoryname-jewellery.html
```

---

5.Need to change From:

```
localhost/laravelproj/public/products/productname
```

to

```
localhost/laravelproj/public/productname-watches.html
```

I hope you understood the pattern . 
I can see `watchtown.co.uk` has done exactly the same (or is it any other way ?)

I created this function in controller for brands:

```
    public function showProductListingByBrands($brandSlug) {

    $brand = Brand::findBySlug($brandSlug)->first();
    $products = "";
    if($brand){
        $products = $brand->products()->paginate(Misc::getSetting('paginate'));
    }
    $products = Product::findBySlug($brandSlug);
    return View::make('store');
}
```

Now how do i manipulate it as my requirement? Im really new in laravel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *scratches head*, does it have to be .html?

Comment: @BrianCoolidge yes.. its must.. :)

Comment: This is a case where you, as the developer, impart your knowledge to your client (as diplomaticly as possible) about why their belief is wrong from an SEO perspective, and that by doing this they're making the urls darn ugly and less expressive. Also, you are accessing *one* PHP file, `index.php`, by putting `.html` on the end without some nasty .htaccess rules you're going to be banging your head against a brick wall with this one.

Comment: wow.. i didn't knew that.. thanks @DavidBarker so what do you suggest? shall i not do it this way? Actually i am recreating a ecommerce site as watchtown.. and it has same url structure in watchtown. I also thot it would save time redirecting the missing (old) urls to the new one.. so i just told the client i'll try.

Comment: No problem. Your best bet is to do some random googling and show your client the url structures of the top ranking results. Take newspapers for example, big stories rank high, not because they have short urls, nor because they have `.html` on the end, but because the content is well structured. Query strings `?a=b` can have a negative hit on SEO (but not in all cases). Laravel does support query string, however in your case they aren't necessary. Build up your evidence and knowledge, then try to educate your client.

Comment: @Geniusintrouble, another tip that I learned about the client & developer relationship is, don't always agree to the client. If you think that this is not a good idea, tell him, and suggest a better way. If you feel that it's going to be pain in the ass or you don't like to do it, tell an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a brief idea.

On your route page

```
Route::get('/{product_name}/', array(
    'as'   => 'product_page',
    'uses' => 'ProductPage@getProduct'
));
```

As you see when the user goes to the page like

Example: `www.website.com/watch`

it will go to the controller `ProductPage` with the method of `getProduct`, so the variable `{product_name}` will be passed on the controller.

Controller

```
public function getProduct($product_name = false) {

    $product = Products::where('product_name', '=', $product_name);

    // Do check product existing record
    if ($product->count() == 0) {
        return  Redirect::route('some-page-error')
                ->with('failure', 'The hell are you doing?');
    } else {
        $product = $product->first();
        return  View::make('product_page')
                ->with('product_name', $product);
    }
}
```

So on method `getProduct`, the parameter `$product_name` is `watch`

So, the method will check if the product exists or not, if not the user will be redirected to 404 page.

If not, it will be redirected to the template that you've made then pass all the product data and display it all there.

But it would be nice if you put the Route into `/product/{product_name}`, also it would be also good if it's product id instead of product name since product name can get redundant.

So yea.

*edits*

I don't know what you're trying to do and why it must be .html, but mmm.. Just wanna give you an idea. Well I don't know if my answer is a good way, someone might give better answer than me.

Comment: Thank you for the post.. i learned few things :).. however this not the answer i was expecting. I need to add .html as the client was it there. If i did as you say.. and want to navigate about page wont' it search for product with name about?